How to handle "Response size greater than Mongo payload limit" in CosmosDB using MongoDB?
I'm experiencing an issue with CosmosDB when running an aggregation query in Mongo shell. The query is designed to match and group data based on specific fields. Despite having indexing on the relevant fields, the query throws an error related to exceeding the Mongo payload limit.
Here is the query I'm running:
db.doms.aggregate([
  { '$match': { domName: 'dider_npi' } },
  { '$group': { _id: '$description', count: { '$sum': 1 } } }
]);

The error message received is:
assert: command failed: {
  "ok" : 0,
  "errmsg" : "[ActivityId=ec6eb377-a2cf-4341-8aec-193677ae3480] Response size 62475470 is greater than Mongo payload limit.",
  "code" : 1,
  "codeName" : "InternalError"
} : aggregate failed

I have already created indexes on domName and description.
How can I modify my query or configuration to avoid hitting this payload limit? Are there any best practices for handling large aggregation queries in CosmosDB with MongoDB API?

It's extremely unlikely that a group with { _id: '$description', count: { '$sum': 1 } } is creating docs which are larger than 64 MB. Maybe if description was 64 MB but I doubt that's the case. So it's probably occurring due to some other stage in your pipeline. I hope you haven't done something like creating an array or string concatenation of descriptions from many descriptions because that's a terrible $_id for grouping, super slow performing and could easily exceed 64MB.

@aneroid - the issue isn't with a specific document, as documents can't exceed 2MB (unless the OP enabled 16MB documents). More likely it's the total response size that's the issue (limited to 4MB in Cosmos DB, which applies equally to the MongoDB API as well as the native SQL API)

fyi there used to be a memory limit related to queries. This was resolved several years ago, starting in v3.6 of the MongoDB API. You haven't shared the version you're using, but... it's something to check.
